# Drupal newbie question

Tags: drupal

Are all requests handled in index.php?

Comment: what do you mean with request?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. All* requests will go through index.php there is a rewrite rule in the .htaccess file which masks this and gives user friendly urls.

```
# Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If Drupal can't invoke these rules then you will see index.php in the browser URL.

**There are cron.php and update.php which don't but these are special files for admin so are not part of the run of the mill site.*

Comment: To clarify a bit: The rewriting block first checks if a file of the requested name actually exists on the given path. If it does, it gets called directly. Only if there is no such file will the request be rewritten to call index.php. That's how e.g. cron.php and update.php can be called directly. So it is possible to place other files in the drupal installation folder and call them directly, thus circumventing index.php (and all drupal logic) - not recommended, though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you're looking for certain code snippets that handles URL parsing and calls various modules then take a look inside `bootstrap.inc`